# How do you extract a time stamp using logstash and grok?

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I'm trying to extract a timestamp using TIME from grok in logstash, but the extraction is unsucessful.

I'm using a grok pattern, but it is not matching or returning anything.

2019-07-30 14:12:23 - **main** - INFO - metro crawler completed runtime:00:00:02

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:crawler}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{TIME:time}
```

I'm getting no matches

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{DATA:crawler}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{DATA}%{TIME:time}
```

See the debug output:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2019-07-30 14:12:23"
    ]
  ],
  "crawler": [
    [
      "__main__"
    ]
  ],
  "level": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "time": [
    [
      "00:00:02"
    ]
  ]
}
```